# Command line execution of Mathematica notebooks and conversion to .m

Tags: packages, scripting

Sometimes one may want to execute a notebook via the command line (for example to run it remotely).

As far as I know it's not possible to run notebooks directly, but `.m` files can be executed, typically with code like

```
math -noprompt -run "<<file.m"
```

So one needs to convert `.nb` to `.m`. 
One way to do this is to save the `.nb` as a Mathematica package and then to convert all cells to initialization cells.

However, this conversion handles some of the typography (e.g. subscripts)  improperly.

Is there a less error-prone way to do this?

---

Edit:

Examples for things that don't convert:

Subscript part notation (`Ctrl+_+[[part]]`)

The corresponding `FullForm` is `Part[list,n]`, the converted expression is `Subscript[list, [[n]]]`.

Comment: Care to share some of the problematic cases?

Comment: Could you paste the `FullForm` of the expression that does not convert and that of the (improper) result?

Comment: I understand the charm in using fancy subscripts to write your programs, but it's good practice to avoid heavy typesetting in code, especially in code that is to be run from the command line. Almost always, the workarounds are localized and probably not worth it. Well, that's just how I see it... fancy typesetting is best reserved for textual data. YMMV

Comment: Which Mathematica version? For 9.0.1 I see no problems really. But of course, you should not write longer programs in the FrontEnd anyway. E.g. you have multiple undo in Eclipse with the Workbench plugin.

Comment: @Rolf Mertig: I'm on 8.0.

Comment: What exactly is “execution of a notebook”? Would evaluating all the [important] cells in .nb-file and saving the result as [the same] .nb-file suffice? It can be done, e.g., using .m-script, with no nb -> m conversion needed. I'll post a detailed answer if that's what you really want.

Comment: …actually, it is not necessary to save scripts as .m files: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28314/1859 (Just discovered this.)

Answer (score 5):

> As far as I know it's not possible to run notebooks directly

It is possible, and there is no need to convert .nb to .m if you want to execute it without FrontEnd.

Notebooks are nothing but *Mathematica* expressions, so it is not difficult to sketch a script that would evaluate all *Input* cells in that expression, add new cells with the newly calculated output, and rewrite the target .nb file.

**The script suggested here erases all existing Output cells in the notebook.** Make backups, or modify the script in case you keep separate Output cells in your notebook.

The script probably preserves the basic notebook structure, but I'm not aware of complete .nb specifications. Notebook backups are recommended.

Suppose, your target notebook file is `test.nb` in `$UserBaseDirectory`.

The content of script file `test.nb.mmaNotebookEvaluator`:

```
Begin["EvalContext`"]

nbFileName = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "test.nb"}];

outputCellPattern = Cell[_, "Output", ___];

cellEval[Cell[b_BoxData, "Input", rest___]] :=
 Cell[
  CellGroupData[{
    Cell[b, "Input", rest],
    Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@(ToExpression @@ b), "Output"]},
   Open]]

cellEval[x : (_CellGroupData | _Cell | _Notebook)] := cellEval /@ x

cellEval[l_List] := cellEval /@ Cases[l, Except@outputCellPattern, {1}]

cellEval[smthElse_] := smthElse

evaluateNotebook = Export[#, cellEval@Get@#] &;

End[]

EvalContext`evaluateNotebook@EvalContext`nbFileName
```

Then, `math -script test.nb.mmaNotebookEvaluator` updates your notebook file via command line. It is very basic, evaluating only Input cells, erasing all Output cells, and placing `Null` as output for expressions with “;” at the end.

`cellEval` maps itself inside `CellGroupData`, `Cell`, `Notebook` -headed expressions. In case `Cell` contains `BoxData`, and is of `Input` type, `cellEval` transforms it `ToExpression`, and the original Cell is replaced with “Input & Output” group of Cells.

I'm not sure if creating a separate context in the script is necessary.

Comment: After 8 years, it is still working nicely (w/ Wolfram Engine 13.0.0). I made a simple shell script to wrap it: https://gist.github.com/tueda/9281f0b894eef9cad09d7e25d48d3a7a

Answer (score 1):

I often had to run slow code on a cluster in a command line.  Of course, you always want to write your code and debug in the FrontEnd if at all possible so it is important to support both methods of opening the file.

My solution was to have my code as a .m file and then dump the output to a binary mathematica file to read later (in the frontend if I was running on a commandline).

The simplest way to do this is to do all of the calculations you need and then dump the global variables. For example,

```
DumpGlobals[save$name_, sub$directory_: "", postfix_ : ""] := Module[{notebookDirectoryExists,outputDirectory},
    notebookDirectoryExists = Check[NotebookDirectory[],0];
    outputDirectory = If[notebookDirectoryExists == 0, Directory[], notebookDirectoryExists];
    If[Not[DirectoryQ[outputDirectory <> sub$directory]],CreateDirectory[outputDirectory <> sub$directory],0];
    SetDirectory[outputDirectory <> sub$directory];
  CaptionPrint["Saving Output to " <> outputDirectory <> sub$directory <>"/"<> save$name <> postfix <>".mx"];
  DumpSave[save$name <> postfix <>".mx", "Global`"];
    SetDirectory[outputDirectory];
];
```

The creation of the output sub$directory is not strictly necessary but made my life easier for automically copying output from the cluster.  The trick here is that getting the directory you are running in for the .m file depends on whether you opened it in the FrontEnd or if you are running it on a commandline (i.e. `NotebookDirectory[]` doesn't always work).

With this output, you can open it up in either an interactive notebook or another .m file by using the `<< myfile.mx`

As for losing the formatting of subscripted variables when using the .m file, they are more trouble than they are worth.  If all you want to do is display code with subscripts and copy them to latex) then check out: [Displaying index as subscript on output: e.g. C[i] -> C_i with Notation[...] or Interpretation[..]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30884/displaying-index-as-subscript-on-output-e-g-ci-c-i-with-notation-or)